# Jquery validation plugin code for password containing at least 10 characters, 1 number or punctuation, 1 upper and 1 lowercase.

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to validate my form using jquery validation plugin to achieve the following criteria:

Passwords Must:

Be at least 8 characters long

Contain at least one uppercase letter and at least one lower case letter

Contain at least one number or punctuation character

I am using following jquery plugin:
https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Here i started some code but unable to write complete code. Please help me to complete it for the above password criteria.

```
        var form3 = $('#change_password_form');

        form3.validate({

            rules: {
                npassword: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },

                ncpassword: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo:'#npassword'

                },
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {

                success3.show();

                error3.hide();

                form.submit();
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Add a method

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
        },
        "Please check your input."
);
```

now all you need to do to validate against any regex is this:

```
$("#Textbox").rules("add", { regex: "((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{8,8})" })
```

This regex is for

```
(                   # Start of group
    (?=.*\d)        #   must contain at least one digit
    (?=.*[A-Z])     #   must contain at least one uppercase character
    (?=.*\W)        #   must contain at least one special symbol
       .            #     match anything with previous condition checking
         {8,8}      #        length at least 8 characters and also maximum of 8
)                   # End of group
```